# Problems with JPanel layouting

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

My GUI looks like this:

[image]

[my gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmNJg.png)

and should look like this:

[image]
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCuy7.png)
and this is my code for layout:

```
public void initComponents(){

    setTitle("GUI-Design");
    setSize(800, 600);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top = new JPanel();
    mid = new JPanel();
    bottom = new JPanel();
    add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(mid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    //TOP Start
    top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Informatik/Technik", JLabel.CENTER);
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/Logo.jpg"));
    JLabel image = new JLabel("",img, JLabel.CENTER);
    top.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    top.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    top.add(image, BorderLayout.EAST);
    //TOP END
    //MID Start
    mid.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
......

}
```

how can I take the huge gap away  in the center and in the bottum ?

Comment: Get rid of `setSize(800, 600);` and instead call `pack()` on your top level window before displaying it. If you need further more specific help, then please create a valid [mcve], one we can compile, run and test without difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipse to develop windows or components (if you are using another IDE, it must have their own plugins).

I think that you have to set up the "grow" attribute of the cells of the GridBagLayout. Probably the cells have this attribute activated so they grow as much as the window size by default.

I hope it helps. Good luck :)